# How to combine two figures in text box

Tags: plotting

Is there any way to combine two figures (a and b) in one text box?  My figures are density plots and produced from different code.

I used this:

```
    GraphicsRow[{a, b}, Frame -> All]
```

but it gave me a text box without the figures.

Comment: What are `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = DensityPlot[Sin[x y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
b = DensityPlot[Sin[3 x y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];
GraphicsRow[{a, b}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: ?? so why `GraphicsRow[{a, b}, Frame -> All]` didn't work and `GraphicsRow[{a, b}, Frame -> All]` does?

Comment: ???huh???  Aren't your two lines of code identical?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just repeated it and it gave the result I want.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork they are, like yours and OP code, what do I miss?

Comment: I know they are the same! I refreshed my laptop and then gave me the results, but any way he proved that my way is correct

Comment: @Ghady:  You would really help everyone help you if you showed us your code for `a` and `b`.

Comment: I know, but my code with huge data and I don't know how to provide it here,there is no uploading, but do you know  my Density plot figures each combined with others Contour plots using" Show and I want to combine them, but when I used GraphicsRow it gave me small size images and I used image size, but it doesn't work , so any help in this and if you can let me know  how to provide my code to see them